# Large number of Sleep connections to database in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Our TYPO3 application is experiencing downtime issues, with the logs displaying the error:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: An exception occured in driver: Too many connections
```

If I connect to the MySQL database and run `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, all I see are lots of connections with the command “Sleep”. This seems like a red flag to me but this is not my area of expertise; is there a good reason for this and if not what might the fix be?

Answer (score 0):

the PHP mysqli Driver allows for Persistent connections.

which basically means a connection is kept open and put to "sleep" till needed again.

this is a tradeoff: an already open connection does not need to be re-establisched so you can query faster. but at the cost that both systems spend some resources (Memory, CPU) on keeping the connection alive.

see the PHP documentation for more details:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.persistconns.php

and configuration options (php.ini)
https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.configuration.php

Comment: We have `mysql_pconnect` set to 1 in the TYPO3 configuration, which I believe should be disabling it. Is there a way I can check if it's enabled and where this might be happening?

Comment: to check the current setting use the TYPO3 Backend Module: Configuration > $GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONV_VARS] which shows you all settings in TYPO3 Conv vars.

mysql_pconnect = 1 (true) should enable persistant connections

Comment: to check the current setting use the TYPO3 Backend Module: System > Configuration > $GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONV_VARS] which shows you all settings in TYPO3 Conv vars.

mysql_pconnect =1 (true) is to use Persistant connects (which sleep if unused) you probaply dont want that. also i am not shure if mysql_pconnect is actually still valid in modern TYPO3 Versions. as they use Doctrine DBAL (and mysqli) and you have to configure it via php.ini

important mysql and mysqli are different drivers and mysqli is the modern one

Comment: Apologies the setting I meant was `no_pconnect`, which is set to 1 so should be disabling persistent connections but doesn't seem to be.